# Spark structured streaming: converting row to json

Tags: java, json, scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to convert `Row` of `DataFrame` into json string using only spark API.

From input `Row`

```
+----------------+-----------+
|       someThing|       else|
+----------------+-----------+
|            life|         42|
+----------------+-----------+
```

with

```
myDataFrame
.select(struct("*").as("col"))
.select(to_json(col("col")))
.writeStream()
.foreach(new KafkaWriter())
.start()
```

using `KafkaWriter`, that is using `row.toString()` i got:

```
[{  
    "someThing":"life",
    "else":42
}]
```

When i would like to get this instead:

```
{  
    "someThing":"life",
    "else":42
}
```

(without the `[]`)

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found the solution. Using `Row.mkString` instead of `Row.toString` solved my case.